# Why is my string matching something in an array when that string doesn't contain any of those characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

Using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.  I can't understand why the below is matching . I have an array of strings and I want to see if my string matches any of those in the array, so I tried this

```
2.4.0 :021 > SEPARATOR_TOKENS = ["-"]
 => ["-"]
2.4.0 :022 > data = "W40"
 => "W40"
2.4.0 :023 > data =~ /[#{Regexp.union(SEPARATOR_TOKENS)}]/
 => 0
```

even though there is no "-" in my string, it is reporting a match.  HOw do I correct this?  Note, I have radically sipmlified this example so using an ".include?" is not an option because what I'm doing will eventually include regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regexp.union` already produces a regular expression, you don't need to use `/.../`

Try this:

```
data =~ Regexp.union(SEPARATOR_TOKENS)
```

Comment: K, I oversimplkfied by example so much, your answer is right, but it misses the point of waht I wanted to know.  Stay tuned for a new re-formatted question I'm goign to ask if you want to pick up some more cheap points.