# Why can't I get my regex pattern to match?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I followed the advice from thsi question -- [How to embed regular expressions in other regular expressions in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057658/how-to-embed-regular-expressions-in-other-regular-expressions-in-ruby) , but I can't figure out why the expression below isn't matching ...

```
2.4.0 :021 > TOKENS = ["a", "b"]
 => ["a", "b"]
2.4.0 :022 > str = "B19"
 => "B19"
2.4.0 :023 > str =~ /#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/i
 => nil
```

I've simplified the example so to illustrate my point but I would like to have the reg ex match (as opposed to doing a string.include?)

Comment: This has already been answered for you before. `Regexp.union(TOKENS)` > `(?-mix:a|b)`. The `/i` you added will not affect the modifier group. TinMan posted a self-explained question later, see the link on top.

Comment: Hey man, I'm trying the solution in there -- /#{ Regexp.union(%w[a b]) }/ and I'm still getting the non-matching behavior.  Exactly what solution were you referring to?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054542). *"To make the regex case insensitive, pass a case insensitive modifier to the pattern and make sure you use `.source` property of the Regex.union created regex to remove flags"*.

Comment: Gotcha.  Goes to show how much I learned.  I didn't even remember asking taht one.